# Unable to contact Host on Android Emulator's browser

Tags: android, asp.net, webserver, localhost

I've a server written in asp.net and running at localhost:5350. 
When i write localhost:5350/About.aspx in my windows browser, i get the about page but when i write 
`http://10.0.2.2:5350/About.aspx`, I get the following Error 
"Bad Request-Invalid HostName"
Kindly help me resolve the Issue.Thanx in advance

Comment: Its near impossible to help you with this infos. Probably a bad web server setup.

Comment: What info do you require?

Comment: What is your asp.net server ?

Comment: IIS, installed with Visual Studio 2012

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin it says "emulator" in the title ;)